# floating div to the right creates gray area on the left

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am creating a div and inside it am creating a table. Then I am floating the div to the right like in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zq9kg/2/). But when I am floating the div to the right, its creating gray area to the left and little gray to the right of its box. The jsfiddle example shows everything fine but the problem is with the actual page I am working on. Do I need to apply any css along with float:right?

Comment: If it works fine in the fiddle then the issue isn't with what's in the fiddle but something else on your page.  Can you link to that page or provide the code?

Comment: is there a particular browser you are viewing this issue in?
Can you upload the file so i could have a look, if this example works we can't debug it!

Comment: Can you try linking your actual page to jsfiddle's [normalize.css](http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css) and see if it works?

Comment: Gray area as in a border? Did you apply a css reset in your css?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to apply any css along with float:right?

Typically, you would also clear that float somewhere else.  That may be your problem, though without the actual code, it is hard to answer the question you didn't ask but probably meant to: *How do I get rid of my gray areas?*